# Are plists in var/mobile/Application/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Documents/xxxxx.plist saved during app updates?

Tags: ios, backup, plist

As the question states, I want to know if the `plist` files in this directory :

> var/mobile/Applications/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/Documents/sample.plist

is saved when an update is released. From this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW8)

It seems that it does get moved when an update is installed. But I still wanted to confirm the same from you guys! (So that I can avoid NSUserDefaults for maintaining 2 int values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, files in your app's sandbox are kept during an update. Though it is possible that files in the `Library/Caches` folder could be purged.

Keep in mind that the value for `XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX` will change during an update.

If you are keeping a reference to a file, be sure you only store a relative reference and not an absolute reference.

For example, if you know you are storing files in the `Documents` folder, just keep a reference relative to the `Documents` folder. At runtime you can get the path to the `Documents` folder and then append your relative path.

Comment: Yeah, I have a method to get the file path every time the app runs. And that file path is what is used to save and read every time, I haven't reference the exact file path anywhere in the code , that's right ?

Comment: As long as you only store the file path after `Documents` or at least after the `XXXXXXXXXXX` part, you are OK.